pgf macros are not updating inside a foreach loop
The pgf macros in my foreach loop are not updating. I looked at Update pgfmath macro in foreach loop, and tried using various definition methods, such as \gdef and \edef. How can I get the trace of a circle by these means? I would prefer doing it this way, rather than use the remember syntax.
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\newcommand{\circleX}[1]{cos(#1)}
\newcommand{\circleY}[1]{sin(#1)}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\lastx{\circleX{0}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\lasty{\circleY{0}}
    \foreach \Vt in {10,20,...,350}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Vx{\circleX{\Vt}}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Vy{\circleY{\Vt}}
        \draw (\lastx,\lasty) -- (\Vx,\Vy);
        \pgfmathsetmacro\lastx{\Vx} % this isn't updating
        \pgfmathsetmacro\lasty{\Vy} % this isn't updating
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



The reason I am asking for a solution without the remember syntax is because I can't figure out how to update the initially coordinate, as in the following MWE. If someone could fix this, then that would solve the problem too. Credit: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/728021/319072
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\newcommand{\sphereX}[2]{cos(#2)*cos(#1)}
\newcommand{\sphereY}[2]{cos(#2)*sin(#1)}
\newcommand{\sphereZ}[2]{sin(#2)}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{45}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\foreach \Vn in {0,10,...,350}{
    \foreach \Vt [
        evaluate=\Vt as \Vx using \sphereX{\Vt}{\Vn},
        evaluate=\Vt as \Vy using \sphereY{\Vt}{\Vn},
        evaluate=\Vt as \Vz using \sphereZ{\Vt}{\Vn},
        remember=\Vx as \lastx ({initially (\sphereX{0}{\Vn})}), % how to parse \sphereX{0}{\Vn}?
        remember=\Vy as \lasty ({initially (\sphereY{0}{\Vn})}), % how to parse \sphereY{0}{\Vn}?
        remember=\Vz as \lastz ({initially (\sphereZ{0}{\Vn})}), % how to parse \sphereZ{0}{\Vn}?
        ]
        in {0,10,...,350}{
        \draw (\lastx,\lasty,\lastz) -- (\Vx,\Vy,\Vz);    
        }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



may I ask why you prefer not to use the specific feature of pgffor designed to enable you to do exactly the thing you want to do?

@cfr I was trying to use it like this: remember=\Vx as \lastx ({initially (\sphereX{0}{\Vn})}), and wasn't able to parse the "initially" part. I'll post an MWE.

I think you need to split the evaluation and remembering parts. I've posted an example of this method and one which just uses tex to do the remembering.

The definitions work, but they are not 'remembered'. The contents of the loop is executed in a local group, so all \def etc. are forgotten. This is precisely why pgffor provides the remember syntax.
If you don't want to use that mechanism, you can use \global\let\macro\macro after defining \macro.
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\lastx{\circleX{0}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\lasty{\circleY{0}}
  \foreach \Vt in {10,20,...,350}{
    \typeout\lastx
    \typeout\lasty
    \pgfmathsetmacro\Vx{\circleX{\Vt}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\Vy{\circleY{\Vt}}
    \draw (\lastx,\lasty) -- (\Vx,\Vy);
    \pgfmathsetmacro\lastx{\Vx} % this isn't updating
    \pgfmathsetmacro\lasty{\Vy} % this isn't updating
    \global\let\lastx\lastx
    \global\let\lasty\lasty
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

However, it is generally easier (in the end) to go with the pgf flow. For example,
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\lastix{\circleX{0}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\lastiy{\circleY{0}}
  \foreach \Vt [evaluate=\Vt as \Vx using {\circleX{\Vt}},%
    evaluate=\Vt as \Vy using {\circleY{\Vt}},%
  remember=\Vx as \lastx (initially \lastix), remember=\Vy as \lasty (initially \lastiy) ]  in {10,20,...,350}{
    % \typeout\lastx
    % \typeout\lasty
    \draw (\lastx,\lasty) -- (\Vx,\Vy);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

Complete code:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\newcommand{\circleX}[1]{cos(#1)}
\newcommand{\circleY}[1]{sin(#1)}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\lastx{\circleX{0}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\lasty{\circleY{0}}
  \foreach \Vt in {10,20,...,350}{
    \typeout\lastx
    \typeout\lasty
    \pgfmathsetmacro\Vx{\circleX{\Vt}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\Vy{\circleY{\Vt}}
    \draw (\lastx,\lasty) -- (\Vx,\Vy);
    \pgfmathsetmacro\lastx{\Vx} % this isn't updating
    \pgfmathsetmacro\lasty{\Vy} % this isn't updating
    \global\let\lastx\lastx
    \global\let\lasty\lasty
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\lastix{\circleX{0}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\lastiy{\circleY{0}}
  \foreach \Vt [evaluate=\Vt as \Vx using {\circleX{\Vt}},%
    evaluate=\Vt as \Vy using {\circleY{\Vt}},%
  remember=\Vx as \lastx (initially \lastix), remember=\Vy as \lasty (initially \lastiy) ]  in {10,20,...,350}{
    % \typeout\lastx
    % \typeout\lasty
    \draw (\lastx,\lasty) -- (\Vx,\Vy);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


not sure what the output is meant to look like, so whether this is 'correct', but it remembers the values properly.

Thank you very much!

@Jasper no, I just meant not saying remember= ... (initially <formula>) where <formula> requires calculating. so also using evaulate or pre-calculating the initial values beforehand.

Got it, thank you for the feedback

@Jasper I just used the comments because the lines were getting long and I wanted to split them without (possibly) adding spaces, though they probably aren't needed.
